# Using Variable Distance Buffer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I am new to ArcGIS.

I have a point shape (Location of a wind power plant) and I want to create a buffer dependend on the diameter of the rotor.

Can someone give me a hint how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think that buffer function http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm
with distance set with option field will help you.

You might need to create new column with distance for each rotor size. I can help you with that if you need help.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for yout fast solution. I´m sorry but I mixed up the terms. I want to create a buffer with the radius / semidiameter. I thought about creating a new collumn in my attribute table, but there must be an more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You will go to geoprocessing > search for tools and enter BUFFER into the search,  then select Buffer Analysis.

Once you select the feature class you want to buffer, you will then notice an option for FIELD (this is where you select the field that holds the rotor diameter)  select this radio button and also make sure you select the correct units (probably feet or meters in your case.)

Once these options are selected, Arc will return a featureclass with buffers around the wind turbines the size of their diameter.

[image]

Comment: Linear units (feet, m, etc) are not available once you choose **field**. You may wind up needing to create a field specifying the rotor diameter in the units of the underlying map.